# What is the easiest way to set up a LUIS bot using C#?

Tags: c#, azure-language-understanding

I have been tirelessly trying to figure out the basic setup for a bot using LUIS and C#. After downloading countless NuGet packages, would someone be able to help me out here?

I'd like to just be able to check my LUIS Application for Intents and Entities, and, for some reason, I am having no luck finding a simple tutorial on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bot Framework team has a number of sample projects in their botbuilder-samples repo [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples). In the 'samples' folder, you can chose 'csharp_dotnetcore' to see a good amount of bots made by the team.

A good example of what you're looking for would be example #12, Nlp-with-LUIS. It outlines how to set up LUIS in the portal, as well as how to integrate LUIS into into your .bot file

This is just an example of a bot, so you can see what a functional bot looks like. The bot framework team has put out a tutorial on integrating LUIS with  C# bot in v4 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-csharp-tutorial-bf-v4).  Once you get a basic bot up and running, you'll find that more specific questions get better answers.